# How to make collapsable ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want the below ConstrainLayout to collapse upon scrolling upwards and then again show up when scrolled downwards.

How to do that?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/score_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/filter_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    >

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please check this one https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: You can achieve this by using the CoordinatorLayout.